# creating a trial version of Visual Basic application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, trial

I created an application in vb.net using visual studio 2010. I want to create an installation file of the application that will not be free with a license so I want to create a trial of 30 jours.if there a way I thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**3rd Party Option:-**

If you are open to 3rd party options, you can check out [Crypto Licensing for .NET](http://www.ssware.com/cryptolicensing/cryptolicensing_net.htm)

**Building your own:-**

The MSDN - VB Developers Center also has a [Shareware Application Starter Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/cc533531.aspx)
You can download this and check this out. This should give you some starting points as well as to how to go about it.

There is also an [old channel 9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/jeffsand/Shareware-Starter-Kit-Demo) of how to use it

*Caveat : This seems to be a bit old* but it should give you pointers to get you started atleast.